# Google maps - get nearest location given thousand of addresses array of strings - haversine formula

Tags: javascript, performance, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My requirement is to show the nearest location on google map given thousands of addresses array of strings.

My research from stack overflow and Google web search lead to this simple solution which is as follows -

1. Get the Geo-coordinates of addresses using maps API
2. Find the nearest point to point distance (crow flying distance) using haversine formula ([here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html))

In this solution I have to hit google maps API n , **O(n)** , times where n is the length of the array of addresses strings - **this is my concern .**

Is there any other efficient solution for the problem as this sounds very common problem.

Comment: are you given in lat longs?

Comment: @John , for addresses i dont have lat-long ,That is why I need to hit the GMap api n times. This is my concern

Comment: Surely you are not restricted to Google Maps API, You can use an alternative bulk geocoding service and then just implement the algorithm in your favourite language?

Comment: @John that can be one case but I have used Google Maps API for other requirements too , that is why i am looking for a solution

Comment: Fair enough. Do these addresses change on a regular basis? the reason I ask is this, say you have 10000 addresses now, but after the system is live new addresses will be added at say 10 per week, you can just batch run the address you currently have, and store their information in a **database** and geolocate the new ones when they are added via google locate and the requirement is met?

Comment: @John i will use your suggestion during my discussion with the client .This is helpful .

Answer (score 1):

As this question is too broad , it needs further discussion on my side with the client .I am quoting @John's comment -

> say you have 10000 addresses now, but after the system is live new
>   addresses will be added at say 10 per week, you can just batch run the
>   address you currently have, and store their information in a database
>   and geolocate the new ones when they are added via google locate and
>   the requirement is met